# How do I create and initialize unique_ptr from a copy of an existing object in a single statement?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

Imagine I have `const Matrix IDENTITY_MATRIX` defined somewhere, ready to be copied whenever I need it as a baseline. `Matrix` is just a `struct`.

If I want to create a smart pointer to a new `Matrix` instance, initialized with a copy of `IDENTITY_MATRIX`, I could do this:

```
std::unique_ptr<Matrix> foo(new Matrix);
*foo = IDENTITY_MATRIX;
```

Is there a way to perform the initialization using a single statement? I don't want to have to write a helper function to do this. If that is required, I'll settle for initialization with two statements.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<Matrix> foo(new Matrix(IDENTITY_MATRIX))`, or just use `make_unique` if available

Comment: @Columbo ahhh, thanks, I forgot I could invoke the copy constructor directly. If you add this as an answer, I'll accept it. Note that make_unique seems to steal the reference, as opposed to copying it, so that wouldn't work in this case.

Comment: `make_unique` does no such thing.

Comment: Weird, my test code is clearly wrong then. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `new` expression to provide an initializer

```
std::unique_ptr<Matrix> foo(new Matrix(IDENTITY_MATRIX));
```

Or use [`make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique)

```
auto foo = std::make_unique<Matrix>(IDENTITY_MATRIX);
```

Comment: Just a reminder... when copying from another unique pointer, be sure you are *dereferencing*, i.e. `make_unique<...>(*other)` and not `make_unique<...>(other)`... An hour wasted.